# I want to add two new fields to a view which is not related to a table with a case statement

Tags: mysql, sql, view, case-statement

1) I am creating a Calendar View and I would like to add a column which checks if the date in that row is a working day if so then populate with 1, else 0.

I have a table with all UK public holidays and in the calendar table I also have a 'dayoftheweek' field where 1 and 7 is SUN and SAT.

Currently I am trying use a case statement, however I cannot run the script as receive the following error:

> SQL Error (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(CASE        IF CT.dayofweek = `1`      OR CT.dayofweek = `7`      OR CT.dt = PH.`H' at line 12 (edited) 
>   This is my script:

```
ALTER VIEW Calendar_View AS
select `calendar_table`.`dt` AS `date`,
`calendar_table`.`year` AS `year`,
`calendar_table`.`quarter` AS `quarter`,
`calendar_table`.`month` AS `month`,
`calendar_table`.`day` AS `day`,
`calendar_table`.`dayofweek` AS `dayofweek`,
`calendar_table`.`monthName` AS `monthName`,
`calendar_table`.`dayName` AS `dayName`,
`calendar_viewtable`.`week` AS `week`,
`calendar_table`.`isWeekday` AS `isWeekday` 
(CASE    
    WHEN CT.dayofweek = `1`  THEN  `0'
    WHEN CT.dayofweek = `7`  THEN  `0`
    WHEN CT.dt = PH.`Holiday Date` THEN `0` 
      ELSE   `1`
    END CASE ) AS IsWorkingDay

from `calendar_table` CT, `Public_Holidays` PH
```

2) I would also like to add another field which checks if the date in the calendar is the current date and so the populate new field with Yes, else No (I tried using a case statement this didnt work).

Answer (score 0):

This is your code:

```
(CASE WHEN CT.dayofweek = `1`  THEN  `0'
      WHEN CT.dayofweek = `7`  THEN  `0`
      WHEN CT.dt = PH.`Holiday Date` THEN `0` 
      ELSE   `1`
 END CASE ) AS IsWorkingDay
```

This is what you want:

```
(CASE WHEN CT.dayofweek = 1 THEN 0
      WHEN CT.dayofweek = 7 THEN 0
      WHEN CT.dt = PH.`Holiday Date` THEN 0
      ELSE 1
END) AS IsWorkingDay
```

There are two important differences:

- `END CASE` is not valid syntax.
- When you use backticks, you are saying that the string is an identifier -- typically a column reference.  There are no columns called `0` or `1`.

Two other issues with your query are the missing comma and the lack of `join` conditions.  Your `from` clause should look more like:

```
from calendar_table ct left join
     Public_Holidays ph
     on ct.dt = ph.dt    -- or whatever the right condition is
```